# Stuck with a type issue using Servant

Tags: haskell

Here's the problem

```
server :: Req -> TVar Int ->  Server API
server r s = tran
    where
        tran ::  Maybe String -> BBuf -> ExceptT ServantErr IO Rq
        tran (Just m) b = do
          h <- liftIO $ atomReadT s
          let eb = EBuf b h
          let nb = Rq eb m []
          liftIO $ atomically (putTMVar (fst r) nb)
          liftIO $ atomRead (snd r)
```

I receive the following error.

```
/apps/workspace/hade/src/Server/Service.hs:36:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘IO Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘EBuf’, namely ‘h’
      In the expression: EBuf b h
      In an equation for ‘eb’: eb = EBuf b h
```

Any assistance would be appreciated
- Carl

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to bind `b` in the `do` block.

```
server :: Req -> TVar Int ->  Server API
server r s = tran
    where
        tran ::  Maybe String -> BBuf -> ExceptT ServantErr IO Rq
        tran (Just m) b = do
          h <- liftIO $ atomReadT s
          b1 <- liftIO b
          let eb = EBuf b1 h
          let nb = Rq eb m []
          liftIO $ atomically (putTMVar (fst r) nb)
          liftIO $ atomRead (snd r)
```

Comment: Argghh! found my problem: function atomReadT = return . atomically . readTVar.  Removed "return".  Thanks for the reply!